# as3 Security Sandbox Violation

Tags: actionscript-3, load, flash, sandbox

I've read all similar topics already with no luck, so I'm posting a new question about this error.

I am trying to load a swf file from another swf file using this code:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader()

//listen for loading progress
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);

//listen for when the load is finished
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onLoaderError);

//load!
var rr:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/Gen-Tree.swf")
loader.load(rr);


function onLoaderError(event:SecurityErrorEvent) {
    trace("hi")
}

function onProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    //calculate how much has been loaded
    var percentageLoader:Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal;

    //use your percentage number here to drive a loader bar graphic
}

function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    //remove listeners now that loading is done
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

    //add loaded swf to the stage
    addChild(loader.content);

}
```

and I get an error messages as follows:

```
SecurityDomain 'http://localhost/Gen-Tree.swf' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///C|/Users/Alex/Desktop/Gen%2DTree%202012/Programming/loader.swf'
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://localhost/Gen-Tree.swf' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///C|/Users/Alex/Desktop/Gen%2DTree%202012/Programming/loader.swf'
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://localhost/Gen-Tree.swf' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///C|/Users/Alex/Desktop/Gen%2DTree%202012/Programming/loader.swf'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to load the external swf off of the file system, which will throw security errors. Put it up on a server, and it should work fine, as long as both swfs are on the same domain. Or run a local server and try it on that.

If the two swfs aren't in the same domain, you'll need to add a `crossdomain.xml`. It'll go on the server root and it'll look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Except you shouldn't just use `*` as it'll open you up to security risks. You'll want to specifically white-list the other domain. You can learn more about cross domain policy files [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html).

**UPDATE:**
Additionally, since the loader swf is accessing the content it is loading (through `loader.content`), you'll need to add security permissions to that content swf (looks like it is called `Gen-Tress.swf`):

```
import flash.system.Security;

Security.allowDomain("*");
```

It's also worth noting that `Loader` is a `DisplayObject`, meaning you can directly add it to the `stage` with `addChild(loader)` instead of `addChild(loader.content)`. By not accessing the `Loader`'s content, you can usually avoid security sandbox violation errors and not have to deal with allowing domains and cross domain policies.

Comment: Actually I am running a local Wamp server. What difference would it make if I upload it somewhere?

Comment: If you're running on Wamp, why are you hard-coding a file system path to load the SWF? Instead of `file:///C|/Users/Alex...`, it should be `http://localhost/loader.swf`.

Comment: I'm not,  it's the loader.swf which is accessing Gen-Tree.swf, not vice-versa.  The error statement is confusing for that very reason.

Comment: Are you opening up the loader swf through Wamp? Or just straight in the browser? The error giving a file system path is odd.

Comment: If I open loader.swf it from a browser, all I get is a blank screen. When I execute it directly from Flash I get upper mentioned errors. Indeed, it's somehow odd.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an additional step you'll need to do.

Comment: I'm gonna try that right now, but I've read somwhere that putting star (*) on allowDomain() involves some risks. I don't remember what precisely though.

Comment: Putting a `*` in your SWF just means that anybody could externally load your SWF into another SWF. Putting a `*` in a cross domain policy file could open you up to many more problems (since it is for your whole server). You can specify your actual domain instead of the `*` if you want to lock your SWF down.

Comment: Well the previous error is gone, but now I get TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. For the same code as i mentioned in my first post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13758/discussion-between-astralmaster-and-ilollar)

Answer (score 4):

You could try to load the swf and than reload the loaders content with loader.loadBytes(). that way you make a bytearray clone of the swf and bypass the security sandbox. till now it works pretty well with images. I explained the process on my blog: http://www.inklink.co.at/blog/?p=14

an example with images follows:

```
function loadPicture():void
{
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("YOUR_URL_HERE");
    var _picLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    _picLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loader2ByteArray);
    _picLoader.load(req);
}
 
function loader2ByteArray(evt:Event):void
{
    var lInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(evt.target);
    var ba:ByteArray = lInfo.bytes;
    reloadByteArray(ba);
}
 
function reloadByteArray(ba:ByteArray):void
{
    var reloader:Loader = new Loader();
    reloader.loadBytes(ba);
    reloader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, reloaderComplete);
}
 
function reloaderComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    var imageInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(evt.target);
    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(imageInfo.width,imageInfo.height);
    bmd.draw(imageInfo.loader);
    var resultBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
    addChild(resultBitmap);
}
```

hope it helps!

Comment: That's delightfully hackalicious.

Comment: @Saariko This does not work anymore. It was patched by Adobe some versions ago...

Answer (score 1):

```
var loader_context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
if (Security.sandboxType!='localTrusted') loader_context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
loader_context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
currentLoader = new Loader();
currentLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
currentLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
currentLoader.load(new URLRequest(baseLink + pName + ".swf"), loader_context);
```

Maybe you can try to add `loadercontext` to it.